# Javascript: Making a textbox display if a dropdown option is selected

Tags: javascript

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

Basically, if the user chooses "SFTP", a textbox should be displayed.

Here's the code I have:

```
<strong class="heading">Image Hosting</strong>
<div id="imagehosting">
    <form name="test">
        Does the client require our company to host their images? <br />
        <em>If you select this option, you'll have to specify what they will be using</em>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category_level" onchange="categorychanged(this.checked)" />

        <select name="category_parent" style="display:none" onchange="if(this.selectedIndex==SFTP){this.form['box'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['box'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
            <option value="1">Library</option>
            <option value="2">SFTP</option>
        </select>
        <input style="visibility:hidden;" type="text" name="box">
    </form>
<br />
</div>
```

The function, "categorychanged", is handled by the following Javascript code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function categorychanged(enable) 
{
    if (enable) 
    {
        document.test.category_parent.style.display="block";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.test.category_parent.style.display="none";
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Right now, if I choose "SFTP", nothing happens. The first part works fine, i.e. dropdown displayed when the checkbox is selected.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV4Ea/) with working code. The issue is the value you are checking against.

```
this.selectedIndex
```

can be just

```
this.value
```

But your code could also use some clean up. First off, unless you have some reason you are not doing so, I'd recommend a library like [Prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). That's going to make your job a lot easier. I would also recommend using [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead of inline events since they are cleaner.

Comment: That worked... thank you! As for using a library, as you can tell, my javascript skills are at the newb level. And this site is just a mockup anyway, but it's something I'll consider. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. And I would recommend a library especially if you're new to it. Libraries make cross-browser code easier, and can make a lot of things you have to do a lot much much easier. Plus the Sizzle selector engine in both is fantastic for finding elements. :)

Comment: Good to know @Ktash. Yet another interesting feature to explore!

Answer (score 2):

You're using selectedIndex, which is a number representing the position of the option element

In this example, Library is 0 and SFTP is 1, so you're doing SFTP == 1, which obviously evaluates to false.

If you want to get the value of option, use

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function changeVisibility(element)
{
    var value = element[element.selectedIndex].value
    if(value == "SFTP")
        //show
    else
        //hide
}
</script>

<select onchange="changeVisibility(this)" >
    <option value="Library">Library</option>
    <option value="SFTP">SFTP</option>
</select>
```

Last, it's ok to write javascript like this when you still learning, but do not do this in a prodution environment... Learn a js library, such as jQuery, and completely separate javascript code from html... It's much cleaner to read and maintain

This is a jQuery equivalent

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(function(){
    $("#myId").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "SFTP")
            //show
        else
            //hide
    });
});
</script>

<select id="myId">
    <option value="Library">Library</option>
    <option value="SFTP">SFTP</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to explain the production method. Thank you @Andre

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in the condition "if (this.selectedIndex==SFTP)". SelectedIndex will give only the index and not the value. To get the value, you have to do -

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```